# SMTP ERROR OCCURS WHEN SENDING MAIL

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am getting an error when sending a mail . I am using SMTP for sending mail . Following are the error details .

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (35944880) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

following are my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                    
$mail->Port       = 465;                   
$mail->Host       = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.com";       

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username   = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";     
$mail->Password   = "*********";
$mail->From       = "XXXX@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName   = "....";
```

How can it resolve . Is any thing I have to done with server settings.

Please help

Comment: How could it be an off topic question  ???????????????????? Am stuck

Comment: What is your host set to? Does "smtp.gmail.com" work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable ssl connections on your host. Or you need to find out if they do have it enabled. If not, then you have to use the regular port 25 or 587.